# Slick Slider does not Autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I have inherited a website with slick slider setup. The swiping works just fine, and the images show one after the other. The only problem I'm having is getting the slider to initiate autoplay when the page finishes loading.

From what I understand the div with class "slick-track" should play the divs below as a slider. The only time it moves is if I change to use class "intro-gallery" but it isn't rotating the proper divs it's just messed up. It does show me that the autoplay "should" work though.

Appreciate any help with figuring it out.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slick-track').slick({
          draggable: true,
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 2000,
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          touchThreshold: 1000,
      });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="intro-gallery slick-initialized slick-slider slick-dotted">
<div class="slick-list draggable"><div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 6600px;"><div class="slide-gallery slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 1320px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 999; opacity: 1;" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide00">
<div class="bg-stretch">
<picture>
                                                                                                                <img decoding="async" src="https://maltbycentre.ca/youthportal/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2023/03/YouthPortalSliders-01-1.jpg" alt="image description">
</picture>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="gallery-box">
<span>Tune in to <strong>Episode 1: The Wellbeing Project Podcast</strong> by <u>The New Mentality.</u></span>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-light" tabindex="0">Listen on</a>
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="slide-gallery slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 1320px; position: relative; left: -1320px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0;" tabindex="-1" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide01">
<div class="bg-stretch">
<picture>
                                                                                                                <img decoding="async" src="https://maltbycentre.ca/youthportal/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2023/03/YouthPortalSliders-02-1.jpg" alt="image description">
</picture>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="gallery-box">
<span><strong>LGTBQ2S+ Affirming Counselling Services</strong> for young people and/or their families.</span>
                                                                                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light" tabindex="-1">Request LGTBQ2S+ Services</a>
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="slide-gallery slick-slide" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 1320px; position: relative; left: -2640px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0;" tabindex="-1" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide02">
<div class="bg-stretch">
<picture>
                                                                                                                <img decoding="async" src="https://maltbycentre.ca/youthportal/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2023/03/YouthPortalSliders-03-1.jpg" alt="image description">
</picture>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="gallery-box">
<span><strong>Join the Youth Advisory Committee</strong> Youth Engagement – Maltby Centre</span>
                                                                                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light" tabindex="-1">Become a YAC Member</a>
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="slide-gallery slick-slide" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 1320px; position: relative; left: -3960px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0;" tabindex="-1" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide03">
<div class="bg-stretch">
<picture>
                                                                                                                <img decoding="async" src="https://maltbycentre.ca/youthportal/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2023/03/YouthPortalSliders-04-1.jpg" alt="image description">
</picture>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="gallery-box">
<span><strong>The New Mentality</strong> is a team of passionate youth, creating change in the mental health system in Ontario.</span>
                                                                                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light" tabindex="-1">Visit TheNewMentality.ca</a>
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="slide-gallery slick-slide" data-slick-index="4" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 1320px; position: relative; left: -5280px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0;" tabindex="-1" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide04">
<div class="bg-stretch">
<picture>
                                                                                                                <img decoding="async" src="https://maltbycentre.ca/youthportal/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2023/03/YouthPortalSliders-05-1.jpg" alt="image description">
</picture>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="gallery-box">
<span><strong>One Stop Talk</strong> is a virtual counselling service providing immediate access to free mental health support.</span>
                                                                                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light" tabindex="-1">Visit OneStopTalk.ca</a>
</div>
</div>
</div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The slider should be initialized on the wrapping container element, `.slick-slider` in this case, and not `.slick-track`. (The `.slick-track` element should not even exist in the initial HTML, initializing the slider will dynamically _create_ this element.)

Comment: Thanks, I did try that but it doesn't autoplay with using .slick-slider not sure why - there are no browser errors.